# Different behavior on table cell width: 0 cross browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, css-tables, column-width

```css
table { width: 100%; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
td { padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<table><tr><td style="width:0">left</td><td>right</td></tr></table>
```

Here is a code snippet: We set width of table to 100%, and set width of one table cell to 0.

The render result is very different in Google Chrome than other browsers. Which render result is the *correct* one? Or are there any specifications about such situation?

[image]

Comment: try using CSS resets for consitency here is a link https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/   hope this helps...

Comment: @ChandraShekhar I'm asking which one is correct, not how to hack on it.

Comment: There is no "correct one", it will always depend on the browser you are using. You can use [Vendor Prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) so that even you are using other browser, the rendered element will be the same as what you are expecting to appear

Comment: @ChandraShekhar "normalize.css" or "reset" has nothing to do with this testcase which i had just tried.

Answer (score 0):

Using display:flex; and float:left; on td you will get same result and view on browsers.